# Thread which runs every 3 seconds

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on multithreading in java and created 1 thread here is the code:

```
class SampleThread extends Thread
    {
        int time;
        String name;
        boolean autocall;
        public SampleThread(int time, String name)
        {
            this.time = time;
            this.name = name;
        }

          public void run()
          { 
              try{
                  time = time +1;
                  updateView(time, name);
                  //sleep(3000);
              }catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            //this.stop();
          }     
    }
```

Now I want to run this thread every 3 seconds how to achieve this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend not doing it this way.  Have a look at the *new* classes (well, not so new) in the `java.util.concurrent` package, especially [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use Java.util.Concurrent for the new implementations.. if you are using JDK 1.4 or below then use the following approach.

```
boolean isRunning = true;
public void run() {
        do {
           try {
                System.out.println("do what you want to do it here");
                Thread.sleep(3000l);
            } catch ( InterruptedException ie) {
               ie.printStackTrace();
           } catch (RunTimeException rte) {
               isRunning  = false; // terminate here if you dont expect a run time exception... 
           }
        } while ( isRunning );
    }
```